# Como puedo forzar que el valor vacio sea el default a cargar en un select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Recibo ese order de valores pero en ui necesito que se carge o este como por default el que tiene un valor vacio

```html
  <select class="required">
    <option value="1">ONE</option>
    <option value="2">TWO</option>
    <option value="3">THREE</option>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cuando agregues preguntas por favor agrega el código como texto con formato de código, no en imagen

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la propiedad `selectedIndex` que te permitirá definir qué índice (Opción) del `select` será utilizada

Es posible utilizar la propiedad `text` (O también puedes utilizar `value`) para comparar y validar la opción que deseas utilizar por defecto

```
if(i.text == temp)
```

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
var temp = "";
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

for(var i, j = 0; i = mySelect.options[j]; j++) {
  if(i.value == temp) {
    mySelect.selectedIndex = j;
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">ONE</option>
  <option value="2">TWO</option>
  <option value="3">THREE</option>
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma sin insertar el item vacio

```js
//CODE Java Script
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    mySelect.value ="";
```

```html
<!-- HMTL CODE -->
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">ONE</option>
  <option value="2">TWO</option>
  <option value="3">THREE</option>
</select>
```